# how to make sure accordion has been loaded before creating accordion using .html()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm having a problem where the accordion html is getting injected onto a tag using .html() first before the accordion gets initiated, thus making the injected html look like an ordinary html.

This is my code in script:

```
$(function() {

$( "#accordion1" ).accordion({
          heightStyle: "content",
          collapsible: true,
          active:false,
          activate:"refresh",
          animate:false
    });

$.getJSON( 'http://localhost/media_books/index.php/new_books.json?provider_id=1&limit=99&offset=1')
    .done(function( json ) {    
        var html = '<div id="accordion1" style="font-size:smaller;" class = "accordion">';
        for ( var obj in json.data) {
            var att = json.data[obj].attributes;
            html += '<h3>' + att.title + '</h3>';
            html += '<div >';

            html += "<p>" + att.author + "</p>";
            html += '</div>';
        }
        html += '</div>';
        $("#tabs_1").html(html);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it inside your `.done()`

```
$(function() {


    $.getJSON( 'http://localhost/media_books/index.php/new_books.json?provider_id=1&limit=99&offset=1')
        .done(function( json ) {    
            var html = '<div id="accordion1" style="font-size:smaller;" class = "accordion">';
            for ( var obj in json.data) {
                var att = json.data[obj].attributes;
                html += '<h3>' + att.title + '</h3>';
                html += '<div >';

                html += "<p>" + att.author + "</p>";
                html += '</div>';
            }
            html += '</div>';
            $("#tabs_1").html(html);
            $( "#accordion1" ).accordion({
              heightStyle: "content",
              collapsible: true,
              active:false,
              activate:"refresh",
              animate:false
            });
    });

});
```

**Why here?** *because :*

> how to make sure accordion has been loaded before creating accordion using .html()

Literaly you mean wait until my `.getJSON()` is `.done()` to first insert the `.html()` **then** do the `$.accordion()`. Which is exactly translated by the code above.

Comment: doesn't work sir, just to clarify, both of them are already inside the $function({});

Comment: @BryanPosas I know that but did you moved the `$( "#accordion1" ).accordion(...)` part in the `.done()`?

Comment: I'm really sorry sir, I never noticed you meant .done in the .getjson Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need the `create` event, which is triggered after the accordion is created --> http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-create